# JSON.parse overrides the original values which result into unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking values from local storage, But when I am doing filtering it is affecting the original values in the storage.

How can I overcome this problem?

```
  const localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("icon"))[`${page}`];

  useEffect(() => {
    let tempData = localData?.filter((item) => item.iconTitle === iconName);
    setData(tempData);
  }, [iconName, page]);
```

Comment: You probably want to be using [`useLocalStorage`](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) and storing that data in state.

Comment: yes, but do we have any solution for above implementation

Comment: how did you use `localStorage.setItem` ?

Comment: provider setData and useEffect function code can help others help you.

Comment: There is literally no point in using that template literal... `[\`${page}\`]` is exactly the same as `[page]`

Comment: @WENJUNCHI `setData` is most likely from `const [data, setData] = useState({});`, and `useState` & `useEffect` are hooks in React (built in functions)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is. Are you saying that somehow this 5 lines of code changes the value in `localStorage`? Because I can tell you right now, that's not possible

Comment: Issues is resolved it was happening because shallow copy, So what I did Instead of directly creating the copy using JSON.parse() I have to not parsed it,

Comment: I have assign value like this const getData = localStorage.getItem("icon");
    const localData = JSON.parse(getData)[`${page}`];

Answer (score -1):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getData = localStorage.getItem("icon");
    const localData = JSON.parse(getData)[`${page}`];
    console.log(localData);
    let tempData = localData?.filter((item) => item.iconTitle === iconName);
    setData(tempData);
  }, [iconName, page]);

  console.log(data);
  const renderTooltip = () => (
    <Tooltip style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      {(iconName && data[0]?.description) || `No Data Available`}
    </Tooltip>
  );
```